# How to add margin between owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I want to add `margin-left` or `margin-right` between carousel items.but not margin-left for first item. below is my code.how can i apply to this.

```
$("#carousel").owlCarousel({
        items : 4,
        itemsCustom : false,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [980,2],
        itemsTablet: [768,1],
        itemsTabletSmall: false,
        itemsMobile : [479,1],
        singleItem : false,
        itemsScaleUp : false,

        //Basic Speeds
        slideSpeed : 200,
        paginationSpeed : 800,
        rewindSpeed : 1000,

        //Autoplay
        autoPlay : true,
        stopOnHover : false,

         //Auto height
        autoHeight : true,
    });
```

Comment: add margin-left or margin-right  in CSS

Comment: @Cattla Thanks!, but if i add in css there is some problem with main container.first and last items not align with container.

Answer (score 21):

Hi You can use this steps

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    stagePadding: 50,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Or you can follow this tutorial :http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/stagepadding.html

Answer (score 3):

Instead of applying the CSS in JavaScript, apply it in a proper stylesheet. Then it becomes simple:

```
.carousel-item {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.carousel-item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. There is some Problem with main container.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS solution:**

What Michael Aaron Safyan said is actually not the "best" way to do it.
The proper way to do it would be:

```
.carousel-item + .carousel-item {
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

If you do it the other way, you're disregarding the whole "Cascading" portion of CSS.

***Sidenotes***

**Owl Carousel 1:**

Make sure you don't set any redundant options for your Owl Carousel.
If you look at the available options, you'll see that many of them are booleans that default to `false`. For instance, all of the following options are default settings.

```
itemsCustom: false
itemsTabletSmall: false
singleItem: false
itemsScaleUp: false
slideSpeed: 200
paginationSpeed: 800
rewindSpeed: 1000
stopOnHover: false
```

If you remove all of these, your code will be the following neat little snippet:

```
$("#carousel").owlCarousel({
    items : 4,
    itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
    itemsDesktopSmall : [980,2],
    itemsTablet: [768,1],
    itemsMobile : [479,1],

    //Autoplay
    autoPlay : true,

     //Auto height
    autoHeight : true
});
```

**Owl Carousel 2**

And just to answer your question even better, if you'd decide to use **Owl Carousel 2**:

Owl Carousel 2 has an option to set a right pixel margin to your slider items by using options ([Owl Carousel 2: Options](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html)). By using this you can keep your CSS to a minimum.

> **margin**
>
> Type: Number
> Default: 0
>
> margin-right(px) on item.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given caused some issues for me where the extra margin on the `.owl-item` caused Owl Carousel (v1.3) to misalign the items—after going to the next slide, a little sliver of the first slide was still visible.

A better approach would be to add the margin to the item *inside* of the `.owl-item`, like so:

```
.owl-item + .owl-item .my-div {
  margin-left: 1em
}
```

Make sure to replace `.my-div` above with a selector for whatever you have inside the `.owl-item`.

As mentioned by @Brannie19, if you're using Owl Carousel 2, you can just use the `margin` option.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me

```
.owl-carousel .owl-item img{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you give a minor explanation why/how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can also change padding only for one carousel:

CSS:

```
.padding-item{
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

and add this class for all the carousel items:

JQuery:

```
    $('#owl-carousel-identifier').find('.owl-item').each(function(i){
            this.className+=' padding-item';
        });
```

By this way, there aren't shift with the border of carousel.